# React.js with router with same component different URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a problem in which I use different react router for same component, using key and exact I can able to reload the component accordingly, but problem here is that particular child of the component should not re-render, it should remain same with all it's values. I am using class component.

Is there any method or trick is there to achieve this one.

Comment: Use a global state management system.Component data gets destroyed when unmounted. You can't get it back. Redux and the context api are common ones

Comment: If your child data isn't too complex then you can also use the react-router `state this.props.location.state`